# Unable to make Grub2 boot Kali with LVM+LUKS

Tags: linux, lvm, grub, boot-loader, luks

I need to dual boot Win10 and encrypted Kali in an UEFI system.

Booting windows is not a problem, i will add an entry in GRUB later, the problem is that as i power on the machine, GRUB loads correctly but gives me just the BASH-like prompt without any menu option.

The drive is shared with Windows but just for additional space, Windows is on another disk.

The disk is partitioned as follow

```
sda
 sda1 Microsoft reserved
 sda2          (NTFS) data partition
 sda3          (NTFS) data partition
 sda4          (ext2) /boot
 sda5 
   sda5        (crypto LUKS)
     kali-swap (lvm)  swap
     kali-root (lvm)  /
 sda6          (vfat) /boot/efi
```

I can boot Kali manually issuing these commands to GRUB:

```
set root=(hd0,4)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/kali-root
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

After that, kali boots up without any problem, i tried running `update-grub`, rebooting but nothing.

i already edited the `/etc/default/grub/` file adding `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="lvm"` and editing the cmd line as follow `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="root=/dev/mapper/kali-root"`

i've tried editing the grub.cfg file on the `/boot` partition

Does anybody know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: No, I personally suggest you edit grub.cfg, update-grub can be frustrating sometimes. Just add an KaliLinux menuentry containing the commands that works

Comment: All right, i'll give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently GRUB was loading the wrong .cfg file.

i found here the answer to my exact same problem

[Grub not loading config file or booting into linux automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232730/grub-not-loading-config-file-or-booting-into-linux-automatically)